# How can I open Wifi Connection System Dialog?

Tags: android

I want to write a application list AccessPoints and when you click one, a wifi connection dialog will open. I searched in the Internet and found some hint:
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK)) – But I can't do it. Please help.

Comment: Try posting more information on what "can't" means. Some idea of what you you want, and how you intend to do it. Would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Settings activity called WifiSettings, iirc. Launch that activity and it will present the user with a list of open access points, their current power settings and some other misc. stuff.

It appears you're trying to duplicate the functionality of the Meraki WifiStumbler, too -- take a look at that app for ideas.

Answer (score 5):

You can start wifi settings intent using

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: Documentation says: > "In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this."